# Kommasetzung bei dass-dass-Sätzen (wenn diese überhaupt grammatikalisch korrekt sind)

Tags: conjunction, comma, subordinate-clause

Man betrachte folgenden Satz, von dem ich überzeugt bin, dass er grammatikalisch korrekt ist:

> Ich denke, dass der Fakt, dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind, schon einmal ein guter Ausgangspunkt für unsere weitere Diskussion ist.

Mein Sprachgefühl als Muttersprachler sagt mir, dass dann auch

> Ich denke, dass(,) dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind, schon einmal ein guter Ausgangspunkt für unsere weitere Diskussion ist.

korrekt ist.

Wenn nein: Warum? Wenn ja: Wie sieht’s mit der Kommasetzung in diesem Satz aus? Setzt man das eingeklammerte Komma?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rein formal ist der Satz korrekt. Der Nebensatz »dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind« ist ein *Zwischensatz*, der in den übergeordneten Satz eingebettet ist und dort die Rolle des Subjekts einnimmt (Subjektsatz). Da der übergeordnete Satz selbst ein *dass*-Satz ist, hat das zur Folge, dass die Einleitewörter – in beiden Fällen: *dass* – der beiden Sätze unmittelbar hintereinander stehen. Ich wüsste keine Regel, die das verbietet. Bei [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Wortstellung.html?MenuId=Sentence64#Anchor-Zwischensatz-11481) gibt es ein etwas weniger ungewöhnliches Beispiel für eine solche Konstellation:

> Ihr solltet jetzt wegfahren, weil, wenn ihr noch lange wartet, ihr im Stau stehen werdet.

An den Regeln zur Kommasetzung ändert sich dabei nichts: das Komma steht vor dem Einleitewort, also vor *weil* und *wenn* oder in Deinem Beispiel jeweils vor *dass*.

Aber bei Canoo steht auch:

> Dies erschwert aber meistens das Verständnis.

Und das gilt nach meinem Sprachempfinden noch viel mehr in Deinem Beispiel, weshalb ich das nur als theoretische Option ansehe. Neben der Alternative, die Du selbst genannt hast, könntest Du auch schreiben:

> Ich denke, dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind, ist schon einmal ein guter Ausgangspunkt für unsere weitere Diskussion.
> Ich denke, dass es schon einmal ein guter Ausgangspunkt für unsere weitere Diskussion ist, dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind.

Comment: @user25138: Bitte beachte, dass Du diese Antwort nicht nur akzeptieren, sondern auch bewerten kannst. Angesichts Deines Kommentars möchtest Du sie wahrscheinlich upvoten.

Comment: Der Satz ist grammatisch völlig korrekt, aber aufgrund mangelnder *Euphonie* ungünstig. Euphonie und Syntax können unabhängig voneinander wirken und sich sogar stark widersprechen.

Answer (score -1):

Meiner Meinung nach sollte in dem zweiten Satz nur ein einziges Komma stehen. Der Ausgangssatz:

> Ich denke, dass der Fakt, dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind, schon einmal ein guter Ausgangspunkt für unsere weitere Diskussion ist.

"dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind" ist ein erläuternder Einschub (laienhaft ausgedrückt) und ist daher von Kommas umschlossen.

Den Satz kann man abkürzen zu:

> Ich denke, dass der/dieser Fakt schon einmal ein guter Ausgangspunkt für unsere weitere Diskussion ist.

Hier ist "der Fakt" eine einfache Nominalphrase. Diese Nominalphrase kann man ersetzen:

> Ich denke, dass *dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind* schon einmal ein guter Ausgangspunkt für unsere weitere Diskussion ist.

Rein syntaktisch finde ich die beiden Satze äquivalent. Daher würde ich formal kein Komma setzen, wohl aber geschickt gewählte Sprechpausen. Schreiben würde ich solch einen Satz jedoch nur unter Androhung von Gewalt.

Comment: »Erläuternder Einschub« – also Nebensatz. Nebensätze werden, § siebzigundetwas der Rechtschreibregeln, durch Kommas abgesetzt. »Nominalphrase« – nein; es ist ein schlichtes Subjekt. »Das Einigsein in diesem Punkt« wäre eine Nominalphrase. Und zu guter Letzt: Selbst wenn ein Nebensatz (»dass wir uns in diesem Punkt einig sind«) die Funktion des Subjekts übernimmt, muss er zeichensetzerisch wie ein Nebensatz behandelt werden. Im folgenden Satz muss das fett gesetzte Komma also auf jeden Fall gesetzt werden: *Dass wir uns darin einig **sind,*** hoffe ich.